# Proof that $A$ is similar to $B$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, similar-matrices

The matrices are defined with $A = \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1&2&-3&-1\\%
8&-7&12&4\\%
6&-6&10&3\\%
2&-2&3&2\\%
\end{array}\right)$ and $B=
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1&-4&7&-6\\%
0&11&-25&25\\%
-4&8&-25&28\\%
-4&4&-16&19\\%
\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}^{4 \times 4}$

Now I have to proof or disproof that $A$ and $B$ are similar. The characteristic polynoms and the eigenvalues are the same. However the eigenvectors are $a_1=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right), a_2=\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\0\\2\\0\end{matrix}\right), a_3=\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\0\\0\\2\end{matrix}\right)$ and
$b_1=\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\5\\2\\0\end{matrix}\right), b_2=\left(\begin{matrix}4\\-5\\0\\2\end{matrix}\right)$

**My thoughts were the following:**

There exists two invertable matrices $S,T\in \mathbb{Q}$ with $S^{-1}AS=D, T^{-1} BT=D$. Where $D$ is diagonalmatrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. The matrices $S,T$ contain the eigenvectors of $A,B$. Therefore we get $S^{-1}AS=T^{-1}BT \Rightarrow [ST^{-1}]^{-1}A(ST^{-1})=B$ and we can conclude that the matrices are similar.

**The problem**

My problem is, that if the matrices $S,T$ contains the eigenvectors, how can they have an invertable, if they aren't square?

Comment: you really ought to compare the Jordan normal forms... you seem to be indicating that neither matrix has a full basis of eigenvectors, meaning the Jordan form tells the full story

Comment: Calculate the eigenspaces' dimensions.

Comment: @DonAntonio aren't they 2 and 3?

Comment: @WillJagy sorry, I don't know the jordan normal form :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two matrices are similar, then the size of a maximal set of linearly independent eigenvectors will be the same for both of them. It follows from this that, if your computations are correct, then your matrices are *not* similar.

Comment: Okay. My eigenvectors are definitly correct. I checked them online. Because the first set has a size of 3 and the second set has a size of 2, we can conclude that they are not similar, can't we?

Comment: Yes. That is what I wrote.

Comment: Okay perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: Sure, thanks for your hint :)